# Find the avarage for each day of the year diractly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to find the average for 'pm1f' and 'pm25f' for each day of the year.
[image: data]

I found the rows for one day using the code

```
random_day = df[df['Hmera'].isin(['15']) & df['Mhnas'].isin(['12']) & df['Etos'].isin(['2018'])]
```

and then i found the avarage of that day

```
avarage_1 = random_day['pm1f'].mean()
```

How can i find the avarage for each day directly, without doing that for each day separately?

Comment: iterate over the 7 days of a week, compute the average and then average the averages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a datetime column, so you could group by it and do your calculations from there.

```
df.groupby(df.DateTimeLocal.dt.date)['pm1f'].mean()
```

You don't have to use a column already present in the data frame and you also can select columns to do the computation on.